# Q.all for resolving array of promises

Tags: javascript, promise, breeze, q

I want to execute an array of breeze queries one after the other. I am using Q.all to perform an action after all the queries have completed its execution.

```
var promises = [];
promises.push(datacontext.breezeQuery(config.breezeEntity.Product));
promises.push(datacontext.breezeQuery(config.breezeEntity.Client));
```

The breezeQuery function mentioned above returns multiple promises I don't want the second query to execute until all the promises from first query are resolved. But I find that on using Q.all(promises), the second query starts executing when the first promise from query 1 is resolved.

How can I ensure that the second query does not start its execution until all the promises (Promise1 and Promise2) from first query are resolved.

```
dc.breezeQuery = function(entity){
  return Promise1().then(function(){
    return Promise2().then(function(){
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "returns multiple promises"?

Comment: As you can see in the dc.breezeQuery function above, there are 2 return statements and both of them are returning promises.

Comment: No. There is only one `return` statement in the `breezeQuery` function. The other `return` statement is in that callback function. Each does only return a single promise.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have an array of queries you want to execute sequentially.

try this:

```
var queries = ...,        // an array of breeze EntityQuery objects
    entityManager = ...,  // a breeze EntityManager
    promise = Q.resolve();

// chain the queries together.
queries.forEach(function(query) {
    promise = promise.then(function() { return entityManager.executeQuery(query); });
});

promise.then(function() { console.log('all queries executed!'); });
```

Comment: Use `reduce` instead of `forEach` for such a thing

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use Q.all.  Something like this.

```
var promises = arrayOfQueries.map(function(q) {
  return entityManager.executeQuery(q);
});

return Q.all(promises).then(function() {
  return entityManager.executeQuery(query2);
});
```